# Auto-coalesce same values into \multirow

Tags: pgfplotstable, multirow, csv

I am generating a pgfplotstable from a data file. In that file, within the `Class` column, subsequent rows with the same value should automatically be coalesced/collapsed/joined to form a `\multirow{n}{*}{value}`. With `n` being the number of subsequent rows with that same value in column `Class`.

The number `n` cannot be predicted when a value is first encountered.
How do I automate this?
If some value (e.g. Mammal) is encountered again later, that row should *not* be moved up towards any previously encountered version.

MWE:
[image: rendering]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Class,Genus
Mammal,Dog
Mammal,Cat
Mammal,Mouse
Bird,Chicken
Bird,Duck
Insect,Fly
Mammal,Bear
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    every head row/.style={before row={
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textcolor{red}{Not what I want:}}\\\toprule},
        after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{data.csv}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    every head row/.style={before row={
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textcolor{green}{What I want to automate:}}\\\toprule},
        after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{
Class,Genus
\multirow{3}{*}{Mammal},Dog
%multirow should be extended automatically with each new Mammal row that's printed
,Cat
,Mouse
\multirow{2}{*}{Bird},Chicken
%multirow should be extended automatically with each new Bird row that's printed
,Duck
Insect,Fly
Mammal,Bear
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `tabular` and `multirow`, this approach goes through the input file line by line and saves a string of Genuses associated with the given Class.  When complete, it then uses a stack to build up the Genuses adjacent to the associated Class.

This takes the input file as space-separated data (see ADDENDUM to this answer for csv-compatible code).  If your entries are single words, this space-separated approach works fine.  If the entries are more than a word, you can either use `~` as a hard-space separator within entries, or you can go the the ADDENDUM at the end of this answer.

Because this approach does not use the `tabular` environment, if one takes the answer outside of the `table` float environment, it will allow page breaks if the data list gets too long.

REVISED SOLUTION (meets the OP's grouping specifications):

This solution is actually simpler than my original approach, which went through an additional sorting step.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,readarray,stackengine}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.ssv}
Class Genus
Mammal Dog
Mammal Cat
Mammal Mouse
Bird Chicken
Bird Duck
Insect Fly
Mammal Bear
\end{filecontents*}
\newcounter{entryindex}
\newcounter{classes}
\setstackEOL{\&}
\setstackgap{L}{12pt}

\def\doubleexpandedCS{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
  \Centerstack\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}

\def\processfile#1{%
  \readdef{#1}{\tmpa}%
  \readArrayij{\tmpa}{mydata}{2}%
  \setcounter{entryindex}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{entryindex} < \mydataROWS}{%
    \stepcounter{entryindex}%
    \edef\theClass{\arrayij{mydata}{\arabic{entryindex}}{1}}%
    \edef\theGenus{\arrayij{mydata}{\arabic{entryindex}}{2}}%
    \def\classexists{F}%
    \ifnum\value{classes}>0
      \ifthenelse{\equal{%
        \csname Class\romannumeral\value{classes}\endcsname}{\theClass}}%
        {\def\classexists{T}}{}%
    \fi%
    \if F\classexists%
      \stepcounter{classes}%
      \expandafter\edef\csname Class%
        \romannumeral\value{classes}\endcsname{\theClass}%
      \expandafter\edef\csname theGenuses%
        \romannumeral\value{classes}\endcsname{\theGenus}%
    \else
      \expandafter\edef\csname theGenuses%
        \romannumeral\value{classes}\endcsname{%
         \csname theGenuses\romannumeral\value{classes}\endcsname%
         \&\theGenus}%
    \fi%
  }%
}

\def\showresults{%
  \noindent\hbox to 2in{\hrulefill}\par\noindent
  \makebox[1in]{\Classi}\makebox[1in]%
    {\doubleexpandedCS{\csname theGenusesi\endcsname}}\\
  \raisebox{.5\baselineskip}{\hbox to 2in{\hrulefill}}\par\noindent
  \setcounter{entryindex}{1}%
  \whiledo{\value{entryindex}<\value{classes}}{%
    \stepcounter{entryindex}%
    \makebox[1in]{\csname Class\romannumeral\value{entryindex}\endcsname}%
    \makebox[1in]{\doubleexpandedCS{\csname theGenuses%
      \romannumeral\value{entryindex}\endcsname}}\smallskip\\
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\processfile{data.ssv}

Not counting the header, there are \the\numexpr\theclasses-1\relax\ class
entries:

\begin{table}[ht]
{\centering\showresults\par}
\end{table}
And here is the following text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted the "Class" to be top-aligned with the list of "Genus"es, then redefining

```
\def\doubleexpandedCS{\strutlongstacks{T}\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
  \Longunderstack\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}
```

would produce

[image]

and if one did not like the small skip between adjacent Classes, eliminating the `\smallskip` at the end of the `\showresults` definition would yield:

[image]

---

**ADDENDUM:**

If one requires comma-separated, rather than space-separated data, then using the new `readarray` package feature, the parsing separator can be set with `\readarraysepchar{,}` prior to the invocation of `\processfile`.

Answer (score 1):

To complement with a `multirow` answer within `pgfplotstable` solution, we can check the next row entry and keep that repetition in a counter. When the next row is different (compared with an `\ifx`) then we branch off to multirow entry. This is possible since multirow cleverly allows for negative numbers for the total number of rows to cover. Then the remaining step is to create another row in the table that holds the unique entries that we have just filtered.

One drawback is that instead of reading directly from file, we need to read it first to a macro then create unique columns (saved under the name `u-<colname>`) and then typeset them with original column name declarations. Here is the complete example

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}


\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Class,Genus
Mammal,Dog
Mammal,Cat
Mammal,Mouse
Bird,Chicken
Bird,Duck
Insect,Fly
Mammal,Bear
\end{filecontents*}

\newcount\pgfplotstableuniqueentry
\pgfplotstableuniqueentry=0
\def\pgfplotstableadduniquecol#1#2{%
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        create col/assign/.code={%
            \getthisrow{#1}\entry\getnextrow{#1}\nextentry% This and next for comparison
            \ifx\entry\nextentry\relax% Compare
                \xdef\tempentry{\entry}% Save it to some macro
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{}% Empty cell
                \global\advance\pgfplotstableuniqueentry1\relax%Increment the dup count
            \else%
                \ifnum\the\pgfplotstableuniqueentry>0\relax% If there is a duplicate
                    \advance\pgfplotstableuniqueentry1% increment for multirow
                    \edef\temp{\noexpand%Selectively expand some macros
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{%
                        \noexpand%
                        \multirow{-\the\pgfplotstableuniqueentry}{*}{\tempentry}
                    }}\temp% Execute the expanded version
                    \global\pgfplotstableuniqueentry=0%Reset dup counter
                \else%
                    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}%Do nothing
                \fi%
            \fi%
        }
    ]{u-#1}{#2}%
}



\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\mytable %Read the table
\pgfplotstableadduniquecol{Class}{\mytable} % Add the unique column

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    columns={u-Class,Genus},
    columns/u-Class/.style={column name=Class}
]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

[image]